# Asking about next week weather

Tags: grammar

So there was a following exercise on the test I wrote yesterday:
What (gap) next week?
It's going to be sunny.

So at first I wanted to fill the gap with "What is the weather going to be", but I strongly doubted it was correct, so finally I decided to put stupid sounding sentence "What's the weather like next week". But I have little hope that is might be correct.
Or "what's the weather like" can be used only when we talk about today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me this sounds a little odd:

> What is the weather going to be next week?

I would agree that *"What's the weather like?"* would generally be used for the current day (or indeed time), but you could apply the same logic to the original question with:

> What's the weather going to be *like* next week?

But for more detailed information you'd likely ask:

> What's the weather forecast for next week?